Filterable DIV Won't 'Show All' Until Button Clicked
I am using the "Filter Elements" example from W3Schools for a page template so that the visitor can filter listings based on the number of bedrooms. The filter buttons are working correctly, however when you first load the page all of the listings are hidden. The "Show All" button is active, like in the W3Schools example, however you still have to click "Show All" before it will load the hidden content.
Here is the W3Schools example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_elements
Here is my test page with the issue: https://lakewoodcampground.com/properties-test-page/
I need the page to load with all of the listings visible. Essentially starting with the "Show All" button active, which it is, but on page load the listings are hidden.


.btn {
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #368BA9;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #555;
}

.propBox {
  width: calc(33.33% - 30px);
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: 4px solid #378AA9;
  text-align: center;
}

.filterDiv {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
<div class="container" id="interior">

  <div id="myBtnContainer">
    <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('one-bed')"> 1 Bedroom</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('two-bed')"> 2 Bedroom</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('three-bed')"> 3 Bedroom</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('four-bed')"> 4 Bedroom</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('five-bed')"> 5 Bedroom</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    filterSelection("all")

    function filterSelection(c) {
      var x, i;
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
      if (c == "all") c = "";
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
        if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
      }
    }

    function w3AddClass(element, name) {
      var i, arr1, arr2;
      arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
      arr2 = name.split(" ");
      for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
          element.className += " " + arr2[i];
        }
      }
    }

    function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
      var i, arr1, arr2;
      arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
      arr2 = name.split(" ");
      for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
          arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
        }
      }
      element.className = arr1.join(" ");
    }

    // Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
    var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
    var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
      btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
        this.className += " active";
      });
    }
  </script>

  <div class="propertyWrap">
    <!-- ACF Repeater = 1 BEDROOM -->
    <div class="propBox filterDiv one-bed">
      <a class="propImg response" href="#" target="_self">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.jpg" alt="beach house" />
      </a>
      <div class="propInfo">
        <p>Site #1234<br /> 1 Beds | 2 Baths | Sleeps 6<br /> Annual Lot Lease: $999</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="propBox filterDiv one-bed">
      <a class="propImg response" href="#" target="_self">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.jpg" alt="beach house" />
      </a>
      <div class="propInfo">
        <p>Site #1234<br /> 1 Beds | 2 Baths | Sleeps 5<br /> Annual Lot Lease: $899</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ACF Repeater = 2 BEDROOM -->
    <div class="propBox filterDiv two-bed">
      <a class="propImg response" href="#" target="_self">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.jpg" alt="beach house" />
      </a>
      <div class="propInfo">
        <p>Site #1234<br /> 2 Beds | 2 Baths | Sleeps 6<br /> Annual Lot Lease: $989</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ACF Repeater = 3 BEDROOM -->
    <div class="propBox filterDiv three-bed">
      <a class="propImg response" href="#" target="_self">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.jpg" alt="beach house" />
        <div class="hoverBlue">
          <i class="fas fa-search-plus"></i>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="propInfo">
        <p>Site #1234<br /> 3 Beds | 2 Baths | Sleeps 6<br /> Annual Lot Lease: $999</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ACF Repeater = 4 BEDROOM -->
    <div class="propBox filterDiv four-bed">
      <a class="propImg response" href="#" target="_self">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.jpg" alt="beach house" />
      </a>
      <div class="propInfo">
        <p>Site #1234<br /> 4 Beds | 2 Baths | Sleeps 6<br /> Annual Lot Lease: $999</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ACF Repeater = 5 BEDROOM -->
    <div class="propBox filterDiv five-bed">
      <a class="propImg response" href="#" target="_self">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.jpg" alt="beach house" />
      </a>
      <div class="propInfo">
        <p>Site #1234<br /> 5 Beds | 3 Baths | Sleeps 6<br /> Annual Lot Lease: $999</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>




You likely need to delay the call to filterSelection('all') until the page contents have loaded something like this may work:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  filterSelection("all")
})

Or for an arbitrary time delay something like:
// Waits 2000ms/2s then makes the call to filter the list of elements (assuming they've loaded in that time)
setTimeout(() => {
  filterSelection("all")
}, 2000)

Note the second option isn't really ideal since it is a guess/race-condition on if the function will be triggered or the network response for the data and rendering in page has occurred it is ideal really to have a "promise"/callback that gets triggered async to handle updating the view once we "know" the data has come back and been rendered into elements.
The first option also assumes all the data and elements are loaded when the DOMContentReady gets triggered from the browser, you may need some combination of things... if show how the data/elements are being populated in the first place then can maybe give a better direction.
Full sample would look like:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" id="interior">

    <div id="myBtnContainer">
      <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('one-bed')"> 1 Bedroom</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('two-bed')"> 2 Bedroom</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('three-bed')"> 3 Bedroom</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('four-bed')"> 4 Bedroom</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('five-bed')"> 5 Bedroom</button>
    </div>
  
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>{
        filterSelection("all")
      })
  
      function filterSelection(c) {
        var x, i;
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
        if (c == "all") c = "";
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          removeClass(x[i], "show");
          if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) addClass(x[i], "show");
        }
      }
  
      function addClass(element, name) {
        var i, arr1, arr2;
        arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
        arr2 = name.split(" ");
        for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
          if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
            element.className += " " + arr2[i];
          }
        }
      }
  
      function removeClass(element, name) {
        var i, arr1, arr2;
        arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
        arr2 = name.split(" ");
        for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
          while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
            arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
          }
        }
        element.className = arr1.join(" ");
      }
  
      // Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
      var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
      var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
      for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
          current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
          this.className += " active";
        });
      }
    </script>
  
    <div class="propertyWrap">
      <!-- ACF Repeater = 1 BEDROOM -->
      <div class="propBox filterDiv one-bed">
        <a class="propImg response" href="#" target="_self">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.jpg" alt="beach house" />
        </a>
        <div class="propInfo">
          <p>Site #1234<br /> 1 Beds | 2 Baths | Sleeps 6<br /> Annual Lot Lease: $999</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="propBox filterDiv one-bed">
        <a class="propImg response" href="#" target="_self">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.jpg" alt="beach house" />
        </a>
        <div class="propInfo">
          <p>Site #1234<br /> 1 Beds | 2 Baths | Sleeps 5<br /> Annual Lot Lease: $899</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <!-- ACF Repeater = 2 BEDROOM -->
      <div class="propBox filterDiv two-bed">
        <a class="propImg response" href="#" target="_self">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.jpg" alt="beach house" />
        </a>
        <div class="propInfo">
          <p>Site #1234<br /> 2 Beds | 2 Baths | Sleeps 6<br /> Annual Lot Lease: $989</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <!-- ACF Repeater = 3 BEDROOM -->
      <div class="propBox filterDiv three-bed">
        <a class="propImg response" href="#" target="_self">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.jpg" alt="beach house" />
          <div class="hoverBlue">
            <i class="fas fa-search-plus"></i>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="propInfo">
          <p>Site #1234<br /> 3 Beds | 2 Baths | Sleeps 6<br /> Annual Lot Lease: $999</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <!-- ACF Repeater = 4 BEDROOM -->
      <div class="propBox filterDiv four-bed">
        <a class="propImg response" href="#" target="_self">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.jpg" alt="beach house" />
        </a>
        <div class="propInfo">
          <p>Site #1234<br /> 4 Beds | 2 Baths | Sleeps 6<br /> Annual Lot Lease: $999</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <!-- ACF Repeater = 5 BEDROOM -->
      <div class="propBox filterDiv five-bed">
        <a class="propImg response" href="#" target="_self">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.jpg" alt="beach house" />
        </a>
        <div class="propInfo">
          <p>Site #1234<br /> 5 Beds | 3 Baths | Sleeps 6<br /> Annual Lot Lease: $999</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</body>
</html>


I apologize for being so new. I tried to implement this and I didn't see a change. It's likely i did it wrong. Is this what you are referring to?

Oh yah actually my bad I didn't see that you actually had the template below the script block there too, let me do some fiddling around with it here in a codesandbox/online editor and see if I can give you a more concrete example of what I was thinking here... roughly what you said is what I was thinking in terms of a combination of the "solutions"/work-arounds but I can circle back here in a few and show a more complete example since you hard-coded the values into the template for now...

I just loaded up your full page here locally to check it out and the CSS and then noticed I had the wrong DOM event was listening for for the page contents to be loaded so I changed that to DOMContentLoaded instead of "DOMContentReady" and is "late enough" in things rendering for your filter code to work properly then.

Thank you! That was it! I probably wouldn't have ever figured that out and I was going crazy. Thanks a lot!
